# Is it possible to put byte[] variable in File()?

Tags: java

I first parse image, and index it in database as byte[] which means the byte[] variable has that image in byte format

[image]
I am going to use images on search list. 
Is it possible to put byte[] variable in `File()`?

`ImageIO.read(new File(byteImage+".png"));`

Comment: are you asking whether you can write a byte array to a file ?

Comment: I need to read byte array by calling it as a file, because it already is a file but in byte format

Comment: I think you really have to edit your post, as you can see from answers people understand a different story

Comment: if you only want to read from byte array to image, use BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes)); like below post. no need to write it to the file firs.

Comment: did you try `ImageIO.read(new File(byteImage+".png"))` ? it might work

Comment: Yes, l understood now better. Thank you also replying, and thank you too @niceman.

Comment: @Munchmallow you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is stored as a png? If so, you can ready it directly from the byte array with:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my life. [link](http://s31.postimg.org/w7ajb9saf/result.jpg). Sorry for small and bad quality.

Answer (score 1):

use `new FileOutputStream(fileVariable).write(bytes);`